# Way to "overlay" multiple tokens/rules/styles with CodeMirror simple mode?

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-modes

A CodeMirror "simple mode" allows you to define a bunch of regex rules that capture chunks of text and apply styles to them. A regex rule can also be used to transition to another mode that has been defined. Here's a really simple example of that:

```
CodeMirror.defineSimpleMode("simplemode", {
  start: [
    {regex: /\[/, token: "meta", mode: {spec: "javascript", end: /\]/}}
  ]
});
```

This just grabs chunks of text that are surrounded by square brackets and applies the [JavaScript mode](https://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/) stylings to it. [Here's a working example](http://jsbin.com/pojawupomi/1/edit?html,output) of that on jsbin.

It produces text stylings like this:

[image]

But what if I wanted to make it so it looked something like this:

[image]

In other words, I want to apply a background "highlight" to the whole captured JavaScript group. Is there a simple way to do that, or is this beyond the scope of simple modes?

Comment: As far as I can tell this can't be done with simple modes, or at least I wasn't able to figure this out. Maybe it can be done with regular modes.